# Failed to get string from autocompletebubbletext

Tags: java, android

i'm using autocompletebubbletext library (https://github.com/FrederickRider/AutoCompleteBubbleText) which display the list of items to chose from in a list and allow in same time to chose the items from the editetxt..

My problem is as follow:
after the user choses a number of items(=Multiple inputs) .. i want to display a text as an output when clicked on a button (depending on the items chosen of course) as explained in this picture: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SydUF.png)..
but i got stucked in getting the string of itemsChosen from the edittext

FIRST: i am not sure which return value to use!!
SECOND: i assumed i should use "checkedIds" and I've tried A lot of solution in internet , i've been trying different ideas all day, from what i have tried: ( Ps: i used a toast to see if the methods did work)

`edittext.getText().toString()` > nothing appears in Toast
 
i have tried to turn the setHash to String[]: then turning the String[] to one string like:

```
    content=editText.getCheckeditems();//getcheckeditems returns checkedIds which is = new HashSet<String>()
    String[] BLANA= content.toArray(new String[content.size()])
    data= TextUtils.join(",",BLANA);
```

it didnt work, in Toast i got"[]"

For the MainActivity.Java (i have the same as here):
https://github.com/FrederickRider/AutoCompleteBubbleText/blob/master/samplelist/src/main/java/com/mycardboarddreams/autocompletebubbletext/samplelist/SampleActivity.java
For MultiSelectEditText.java (i Have same as here) : 
https://github.com/FrederickRider/AutoCompleteBubbleText/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/mycardboarddreams/autocompletebubbletext/MultiSelectEditText.java

WHAT is the solution? (to get a string so i can use it later) 
PS: if there is another way(another library or methode) to get what i want to achieve in the first place , i would love to try it..

EDIT: THIS IS A CODE THAT LOOKS PROMISING BUT DIDN'T WORK!

in MultiSelectEditText.java

```
public String datachosen(){
        String [] blan= checkedIds.toArray(new String[0]);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String string : blan) {
            if (builder.length() > 0) {
                builder.append(" ");
            }
            builder.append(string);
        }

        String DATATORETURN = builder.toString();
        return DATATORETURN;
    }
```

in MAINACTIVTY.JAVA

```
MultiSelectEditText editText = (MultiSelectEditText)findViewById(R.id.auto_text_complete);
content=editText.datachosen();
Toast.makeText(DecisionTree.this, content,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // TOAST INCLUDED IN A BUTTON OF COURSE
```

OUTPUT: TOAST SHOWS NOTHING!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it ..
i intialize the edit text before on create ..and defin it later after onCreate()..
and got string with the normal edittext.getText().toString(); method!

Simple but was hard to detect the problem!